# Create an insert and pop method on list class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I need to implement an insert method (insert(self, index, val)), that inserts val before index, and a pop method (pop(self)), that removes the last element from mylist, onto the MyList class. The behavior should be identical to the methods already available in python.

Note: For the insert method, similarly with the append method already done, the capacity of the array should be doubled if there is no room for an additional element. The pop method should return the element removed from the list, and put None
in its place in the array. If pop was called on an empty list, an IndexError
exception should be raised.

My code thus far:

```
import ctypes  # provides low-level arrays
def make_array(n):
    return (n * ctypes.py_object)()

class MyList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = make_array(1)
        self.capacity = 1
        self.n = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.n


    def append(self, val):
        if(self.n == self.capacity):
            self.resize(2 * self.capacity)
        self.data[self.n] = val
        self.n += 1

    def resize(self, new_size):
        new_array = make_array(new_size)
        for ind in range(self.n):
            new_array[ind] = self.data[ind]
        self.data = new_array
        self.capacity = new_size

    def extend(self, other):
        for elem in other:
            self.append(elem)

    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        if not(0 <= ind <= self.n - 1):
            raise IndexError('MyList index is out of range')
        return self.data[ind]

    def __setitem__(self, ind, val):
        if not(0 <= ind <= self.n - 1):
            raise IndexError('MyList index is out of range')
        self.data[ind] = val

mylst1 = MyList()
for i in range(5):
    mylst1.append(i)
```

Comment: Consider that the variable n can both grow and shrink depending on what is needed. You already have n growing when you append, so for the pop function consider setting the value of the last index (n in this case) to None, and subtracting 1 from n. You can also use n to help look for the time to throw an IndexError.

For insert, you first need to check capacity to determine if there is enough room on the current array to put another value. The function will be a similar operation to your append and resize, in the sense of checking size, and using multiple arrays and setting data in a loop

Comment: Thank you, I will consider setting the last index to None as you suggested.

Comment: Michael, it's the value at the index you would set to null. Not the index itself. The index would be index - 1